# Multiplication without using the times or division symbol in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
else:
    while int(n2) - 1 != 0:
        a = int(n) + int(n)
        print("" + str(a))
```

I need this part of code to times n by n2 without using '*' or '/' and I'm not sure how to change this so that it will work. What do I need to change/add to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
lowest, highest = a, b
if b < a: lowest, highest = b, a
total = 0
for _ in range(lowest):
    total += highest
print "a x b = %s" % total
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to add `n` to `ans` exactly `n2` times:

```
n = 30
n2 = 2
ans = 0
for i in range(n2):
    ans += n
print(ans)
```

If you need to operate on strings (as in your question), you could use the following example:

```
n = '30'
n2 = '2'
ans = 0
for i in range(int(n2)):
    ans += int(n)
print(str(ans))
```